# How to get demographics data or insights using Twitter API,

Tags: twitter

I have seen reports simplymeasured, twitter counter, tweetstats etc..
i have used Twitter api, i have looked into the documentation. I found no method to fetch Analytic data.
So, i wonder how do they prepare these data. Do i have to save all the data for each user and my own?

Comment: Yes, you need to save the data for each user on your own.

Comment: So, Stats for twitter account will cost me database.